# forecasting problem

Tags: time-series, forecasting, dataset

I have two questions.

1- I have weather data of 10 turbines and I know their collective production(Power).I also know maximum power a turbine can make. How can I forecast collective production if I know individual turbine weather condition?

**Power Data**

```
    Time                       Power Produced(MW)        
    2010-11-11 00:00:00+00:00     248.367512
```

**Weather Data**

```
time    Temperature     RelativeHumidity    Wind_U  Wind_V    Pressure  CloudCover  WindGustSpeed   latitude    longitude
2010-11-11  80.060944    0.959463         4.791473  3.756961    99201.50    0.999969    9.061006    55.003349   9.983611
```

2- Moreover, I have more than one value for one hour weather like  2010-11-11 (100F 30.3m/s) ,and there is another set of values for same date like 2010-11-11 (99.8F 30.1m/s). How can I use those multiple values for single date?

Answer (score 0):

If you only know collective past production and not the production of every turbine or even their share of production, you can only forecast the collective production instead of forecasting every turbine and then combining the forecasts. This will most likely lead to less accurate results.

If this is the case, you'll have to combine the weather conditions into some sort of average. You could also calculate minimums, maximums or even quantiles of all the weather variables and add them as predictors in addition to the predictors you already have. The latitude and longitude would then be constant and cannot be used as predictors.

If you are forecasting the production of a single date, you'll have to aggregate all the variables to daily. Again, you could try different functions but in this case the mean might make most sense.